# Is there any way to generate all the possible undirected graphs with unlabeled nodes?

Tags: graphs, algorithms

**I am looking for an efficient algorithm to generate all of the unique graphs for a given number of nodes.**

For small instances, the total number of graphs are as follows:

n=2 G=2

n=3 G=4

n=4 G=11

n=5 G=34

I used the complementarity property of graphs to make it easier to enumerate all of them.

[image]

[image: [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAE51.png]

Comment: What’s your question exactly? Are you asking for a way to do this? It seems you have a way in mind already.

Comment: I am looking for a method to track all the generated graphs. A simple algorithm is to generate all $2^{{n}\choose{2}}$ cases. But, as the number of nodes increases, the difference between the total number of unique graphs and that number super exponentially grows. I have some basic idea but for large n's it doesn't work since some weird cases happen. I wanted to realize whether there exists any method for it or not. The method should ensure that at each step we have a new graph. I am not sure but I think realizing the similarity of two unlabeled and undirected graphs is an NP-hard problem.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something obvious, but what is the connection to OR? this should be in the CS or math stackexchange.

Comment: @Michael Feldmeier Graph theory is part of/aplicable to OR. True it could be postedoin another SE site. But that is ture for almost every OR SE question. I take a big, flexible, and evolving tent view of OR, and apparently have a bigger and more flexible tent view of OR than you do (and not just based on this question)..

Comment: To me this question is on the borderline. I think math or CS might have been a better fit for this question, but I think it's close enough that I'm not planning to cast a close vote (or, probably, an open vote, if it gets closed). I think graph theory is close enough to OR (especially since there is an algorithmic aspect to this question) that it can be in scope.

Comment: But my larger question is, I don't really understand what is being asked here. @RaminFakhimi are you asking for an algorithm to generate the *number* of unique graphs of size $n$, or the graphs themselves? It seems you are asking for the graphs, but OTOH the answer by Rob Pratt only provides a number, and you accepted that answer.

Comment: Actually, I am looking for an algorithm that ensures if we gave it enough time, it would be able to efficiently generate all the unique graphs for the specific number of nodes.

Comment: As [Beasley's webpage](http://people.brunel.ac.uk/~mastjjb/jeb/or/graph.html) or a [simple search](https://www.google.com/search?q=graph+theory+Operations+Research) shows "graph theory" is a part of Operations Research. I think this question would be better if Ramin mentioned *how* (why) he intended to apply this to OR rather than leaving it as a question that might be better asked elsewhere. I'm going to vote against closing.

Comment: I think [Daft](http://daft-pgm.org/) would be a simple way of drawing the graphs, but I haven't been able to find an example program.

Answer (score 7):

See http://oeis.org/A000088, which gives a different number (34) for n = 5.

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer. OTOH the OP accepted it, so...

Comment: I think the link leads to a good source of materials for this question.

Answer (score 5):

There is a program that generates those graphs for the small number of vertices.
[http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/data/graphs.html](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/%7Ebdm/data/graphs.html)

The following code converts the file with the g6 format to an array (it is written in python).

````py
import numpy as np

file_contents = open("graph3c.txt", "r")

lines = file_contents.readlines()

for line in lines:

    n = ord(line.split()[0][0]) - 63
    h = ''

    l = n - 1
    for i in range(1,l):
        temp = bin(ord(line.split()[0][i])-63)[2:]
        if len(temp) < 6:
            for k in range(6 - len(temp)):
                h = h + '0'
        h = h + temp
    
     
    A = [[0]*n for j in range(n)]
    k = 0;
    for i in range(1,n):
        for j in range(0,i):
            A[i][j] = int(h[k])
            A[j][i] = A[i][j]
            k = k+1

```
````

Answer (score 2):

I've seen several researchers using the NAUTY package to generate all graphs of a given size:

https://pallini.di.uniroma1.it/

Answer (score 1):

The [GraphsInGraphs](https://www.gerad.ca/Gilles.Caporossi/GIG/) contains a database of all undirected graphs with up to 10 nodes, and code to generate larger ones. One of the original goals was to detect sub-graphs and isomorphisms.

You can find the mathematical background here: https://www.gerad.ca/fr/papers/G-2016-10